# tx_news_domian_model_news accidentally deleted fron the database (in phpMyAdmin) by clicking EMPTY and Truncate

Tags: phpmyadmin, typo3-6.2.x, tt-news

we use Typo 3 6.2.41 and have the plugin tt_news not sure which Version.
How can we restore the deleted table?

Thank you

Best Regards 
Carmen

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, neither phpMyAdmin nor MySQL have built-in "trash can" functionality. You should restore from a backup in order to get your data back.

Comment: Hello Isaac, thank you for your answer. We were lucky we had Backup for the last 7 days and recoverd the emptied data from there.